# How to achieve falling effect in cocos2d without physics

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to show an effect of falling blocks which settle down at pre-determined position after some falling animation.
Can this be done without using physics engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better and easier way to do this in cocos2d by using CCJumpTo action

```
CCActionInterval *jump1 = [CCJumpTo actionWithDuration:3 position:sp.position height:150 jumps:2];
sp.position = ccp(10,100);
[sp runAction:jump1];
```

Where sp is the CCSprite for the block.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to simulate gravity, the acceleration of the object. This could be achieved quite easily with a custom animation curve. Please have a look at this [QA "how-to-create-custom-easing-function-with-core-animation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161465/how-to-create-custom-easing-function-with-core-animation), which shows a way to create the curve you need. Here [is some more about "Animation Types Timing" by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/Timing.html).

The function you are looking for is called 
[functionWithControlPoints](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004505-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2), which has four input parameteres, so yes you can put in any random element you wish with a custom curve.

Comment: Can i generate curves algorithmically with some random component?

Answer (score 0):

"Easing" is your answer. You can choose the method that you need visually from the links below.

[Tim Groleau's easing generator](http://timotheegroleau.com/Flash/experiments/easing_function_generator.htm)

[jQuery Easing Demos](http://jqueryui.com/easing/)