# Error and warning using 'GetTiming()' function for CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, cakeyframeanimation

I'm having one error and one warning concerning the usage of the 'GetTiming()' function. My colde is as follows:

```
[values addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.0]];
[timings addObject:GetTiming(kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)];
[keytimes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
```

I am importing the following:

```
#import <QuartzCore/CAAnimation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/CAMediaTimingFunction.h>
```

The error I suppose is due to the fact that I'm using ARC, and says:

```
implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC.
```

I tried to disable ARC in the concerning file but the error persists.

About the warning, it says:

```
implicit declaration of function 'GetTiming' is invalid in C99
```

Any one have any ideas on how can I fix these issues?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure that the `GetTiming` function exists (include the right header). Now if `GetTiming` returns an `int` the problem is you can not add a primitive value to an array. You need to wrap the value returned in an `NSNumber`.

```
[timings addObject:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:GetTiming(kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)]];
```

Edit:

You are missing the function that was declared in [`JackController.m`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5161588/734702).

```
CAMediaTimingFunction* GetTiming(NSString* name) {
    return [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:name];
}
```

For simplicity do not use that function, just create it directly.

```
[timings addObject:
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
```

Comment: It solved the ARC issue, however the warning still persists, and when try to build it fails with the message: Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_GetTiming". Thanks anyway!

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do because you are calling `GetTiming` like it is a C function. And by the name of it it looks like it would be a function you wrote. I looked at the documentation for `CAMediaTimingFunction` and it is an Objective-C class and there is no function called `GetTiming`. There is an example in the Animation Pacing section here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/Timing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006670-SW1

Comment: I want to create an animation bounce effect in a similar way as proposed by Felz in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5161588/734702

Comment: @BrunoMorgado Answer updated, that should take care of your problem

Comment: Yeah, I totally missed it. Thanks very much!