# how to add bounce animation to animateWithDuration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation, animatewithduration

I have a simple animation that im performing in my scroll view delegate method `scrollViewDidEndDragging`.

It looks like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {

    NSLog(@"finger was lifted");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                         self.homeLabel.frame = self.view.frame;
                    }];
}
```

Using this animation after lifting the finger the my `homeLabel` is coming from top, and i want to add it a bounce animation to the label, so when it comes from top, instead of landing smoothly it will have a nice bounce...how can i DO THAT? thanksss

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `usingSpringWithDamping` animation function.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.2 initialSpringVelocity:5.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    self.homeLabel.frame = self.view.frame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

Adjusting the `Spring Damping` and `Initial Spring Velocity` can give you the effect you want.

Comment: This is the best answer. (voted.) The `animateWithDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:` method is tailor-made for what the OP is asking to do. I wrote a demo program on github that animates the hands of a clock using exactly this call and it gives a very realistic bounce look.

Answer (score 0):

One good solution is to create a custom layer for your view that overrides the `addAnimation:forKey:` method to include a custom timing function.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16848847/600753) goes into the specifics of how to do that.

Another option is to take a look at key frame animation. This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161465/how-to-create-custom-easing-function-with-core-animation) covers that approach very well.