# Animating a UIView without using CoreAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-animation

I'm trying to move a UIVIew across the screen. I don't want to use CoreAnimation because I need to be able to vary the velocity of the view in real-time.

At the moment I have the following hierarchy:

```
UIView
-- UIView (subview)
```

I'm sub-classing the parent view and adding an update method.

```
-(void) update: (float) dt {

    float newX = _subView.transform.tx + dt * dxdt;

    [_subView setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(newX, 0)];
}
```

The update method is called every frame and I was hoping that this would cause the sub view to be animated.

Unfortunately it doesn't move. I've tried:

```
[_subView setNeedsDisplay]
```

But it still doesn't work. There must be something I'm missing to force the view to re-draw.

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Autolayout is disabled.

Comment: What do you mean, "the update method is called every frame"? How are you calling this method?

Comment: It's called from a separate thread i.e. 60 times per second

Comment: Don't ever change properties of views from a separate thread, UIKit is *not* thread-safe.

Comment: How would you recommend I animate the view in that case? I need to be able to change the view's velocity in real time.

Comment: I would do it by turning on auto layout, and animating one of the constraints using a CADisplayLink for the timing.

Comment: What you're trying to do can be accomplished with Core Animation. You should look at creating a custom timing function. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161465/how-to-create-custom-easing-function-with-core-animation