# table view cell animation like google maps menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

I'm trying to build an animated transition similar to the Google Inbox or Google Maps animation:

[image]

I'm trying to switch between different sets of table view cells. I'd like the old table view cells to fade out (which I can do using tableView rowAnimations) and the new table view cells to slide in from the top or scrunch down from the bottom.

I've tried using UITableView methods deleteSections, deleteRows, insertSections, insertRows but I can't replicate the effect. I'm thinking that maybe I should use tableViewWillDisplayCell to perform custom animations but I'm not sure.

Any comments or suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: I've included a gif of the animation I'm trying to replicate 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/CwkUb.gif

Comment: I just opened a 500 bounty on [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26632893/1445366) - you might want to keep an eye on any answers that appear there.