# iOS complex animation coordination like Android Animator(Set)

Tags: ios, swift, ios-animations

I've made a fairly complex animation in my Android app using Animator classes. I want to port this animation to iOS. Preferably it is somewhat like the Android Animator. I've looked around and nothing seems to be what I want. The closest I got was with CAAnimation. But unfortunately all child delegates get ignored if they're put in a group.

Let me start with the animation I made on Android. I'm animating three view groups (which contains an ImageView and a TextView). Per button I have an animation which translates the view to the left and simultaneously animate the alpha to 0. After that animation there is another animation which translates the same view in from the right to the original position and also animates the alpha back to 1. There is one view which also has a scale animation besides the translate and alpha animation. All the views are using different timing functions (easing). The animating in and animating out is different and one view has a different timing function for the scale while the alpha and translate animation uses the same. After the first animation ends I'm setting the values to prepare the second animation. The duration of the scale animation is also shorter than the translate and alpha animation. I'm putting the single animations (translate and alpha) inside an AnimatorSet (basically a group for animations). This AnimatorSet is put in another AnimatorSet to run the animations after eachother (first animate and than in). And this AnimatorSet is put in another AnimatorSet which runs the animation of all 3 buttons simultaneously.

Sorry for the long explanation. But this way you understand how I'm trying to port this to iOS. This one is too complex for the UIView.animate(). CAAnimation overrides delegates if put into a CAAnimationGroup. ViewPropertyAnimator doesn't allow custom timing functions to my knowledge and can't coordinate multiple animations.

Does anybody have an idea what I could use for this? I'm also fine with a custom implementation which gives me a callback each animation tick so I can update the view accordingly.

---

**Edit**

The Android animation code:

```
fun setState(newState: State) {
    if(state == newState) {
        return
    }

    processing = false

    val prevState = state
    state = newState

    val reversed = newState.ordinal < prevState.ordinal

    val animators = ArrayList<Animator>()
    animators.add(getMiddleButtonAnimator(reversed, halfAnimationDone = {
        displayMiddleButtonState()
    }))

    if(prevState == State.TAKE_PICTURE || newState == State.TAKE_PICTURE) {
        animators.add(getButtonAnimator(leftButton, leftButton, leftButton.imageView.width.toFloat(), reversed, halfAnimationDone = {
            displayLeftButtonState()
        }))
    }

    if(prevState == State.TAKE_PICTURE || newState == State.TAKE_PICTURE) {
        animators.add(getButtonAnimator(
            if(newState == State.TAKE_PICTURE) rightButton else null,
            if(newState == State.CROP_PICTURE) rightButton else null,
            rightButton.imageView.width.toFloat(),
            reversed,
            halfAnimationDone = {
                displayRightButtonState(inAnimation = true)
            }))
    }

    val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
    animatorSet.playTogether(animators)
    animatorSet.start()
}

fun getButtonAnimator(animateInView: View?, animateOutView: View?, maxTranslationXValue: Float, reversed: Boolean, halfAnimationDone: () -> Unit): Animator {
    val animators = ArrayList<Animator>()

    if(animateInView != null) {
        val animateInAnimator = getSingleButtonAnimator(animateInView, maxTranslationXValue, true, reversed)
        if(animateOutView == null) {
            animateInAnimator.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
                    halfAnimationDone()
                }
            })
        }
        animators.add(animateInAnimator)
    }

    if(animateOutView != null) {
        val animateOutAnimator = getSingleButtonAnimator(animateOutView, maxTranslationXValue, false, reversed)
        animateOutAnimator.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                halfAnimationDone()
            }
        })
        animators.add(animateOutAnimator)
    }

    val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
    animatorSet.playTogether(animators)

    return animatorSet
}

private fun getSingleButtonAnimator(animateView: View, maxTranslationXValue: Float, animateIn: Boolean, reversed: Boolean): Animator {
    val translateDuration = 140L
    val fadeDuration = translateDuration

    val translateValues =
        if(animateIn) {
            if(reversed) floatArrayOf(-maxTranslationXValue, 0f)
            else floatArrayOf(maxTranslationXValue, 0f)
        } else {
            if(reversed) floatArrayOf(0f, maxTranslationXValue)
            else floatArrayOf(0f, -maxTranslationXValue)
        }
    val alphaValues =
        if(animateIn) {
            floatArrayOf(0f, 1f)
        } else {
            floatArrayOf(1f, 0f)
        }

    val translateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animateView, "translationX", *translateValues)
    val fadeAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animateView, "alpha", *alphaValues)

    translateAnimator.duration = translateDuration
    fadeAnimator.duration = fadeDuration

    if(animateIn) {
        translateAnimator.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(Ease.CUBIC_OUT)
        fadeAnimator.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(Ease.CUBIC_OUT)
    } else {
        translateAnimator.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(Ease.CUBIC_IN)
        fadeAnimator.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(Ease.CUBIC_IN)
    }

    val animateSet = AnimatorSet()
    if(animateIn) {
        animateSet.startDelay = translateDuration
    }
    animateSet.playTogether(translateAnimator, fadeAnimator)

    return animateSet
}

fun getMiddleButtonAnimator(reversed: Boolean, halfAnimationDone: () -> Unit): Animator {
    val animateInAnimator = getMiddleButtonSingleAnimator(true, reversed)
    val animateOutAnimator = getMiddleButtonSingleAnimator(false, reversed)

    animateOutAnimator.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
            halfAnimationDone()
        }
    })

    val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
    animatorSet.playTogether(animateInAnimator, animateOutAnimator)

    return animatorSet
}

private fun getMiddleButtonSingleAnimator(animateIn: Boolean, reversed: Boolean): Animator {
    val translateDuration = 140L
    val scaleDuration = 100L
    val fadeDuration = translateDuration
    val maxTranslationXValue = middleButtonImageView.width.toFloat()

    val translateValues =
        if(animateIn) {
            if(reversed) floatArrayOf(-maxTranslationXValue, 0f)
            else floatArrayOf(maxTranslationXValue, 0f)
        } else {
            if(reversed) floatArrayOf(0f, maxTranslationXValue)
            else floatArrayOf(0f, -maxTranslationXValue)
        }
    val scaleValues =
        if(animateIn) floatArrayOf(0.8f, 1f)
        else floatArrayOf(1f, 0.8f)
    val alphaValues =
        if(animateIn) {
            floatArrayOf(0f, 1f)
        } else {
            floatArrayOf(1f, 0f)
        }

    val translateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(middleButtonImageView, "translationX", *translateValues)
    val scaleXAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(middleButtonImageView, "scaleX", *scaleValues)
    val scaleYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(middleButtonImageView, "scaleY", *scaleValues)
    val fadeAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(middleButtonImageView, "alpha", *alphaValues)

    translateAnimator.duration = translateDuration
    scaleXAnimator.duration = scaleDuration
    scaleYAnimator.duration = scaleDuration
    fadeAnimator.duration = fadeDuration

    if(animateIn) {
        translateAnimator.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(Ease.QUINT_OUT)
        scaleXAnimator.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(Ease.CIRC_OUT)
        scaleYAnimator.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(Ease.CIRC_OUT)
        fadeAnimator.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(Ease.QUINT_OUT)
    } else {
        translateAnimator.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(Ease.QUINT_IN)
        scaleXAnimator.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(Ease.CIRC_IN)
        scaleYAnimator.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(Ease.CIRC_IN)
        fadeAnimator.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(Ease.QUINT_IN)
    }

    if(animateIn) {
        val scaleStartDelay = translateDuration - scaleDuration
        val scaleStartValue = scaleValues[0]

        middleButtonImageView.scaleX = scaleStartValue
        middleButtonImageView.scaleY = scaleStartValue

        scaleXAnimator.startDelay = scaleStartDelay
        scaleYAnimator.startDelay = scaleStartDelay
    }

    val animateSet = AnimatorSet()
    if(animateIn) {
        animateSet.startDelay = translateDuration
    }
    animateSet.playTogether(translateAnimator, scaleXAnimator, scaleYAnimator)

    return animateSet
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

Here is a video of how the animation looks on Android:

https://youtu.be/IKAB9A9qHic

Comment: Maybe (just saying maybe) this can help you http://www.quartzcodeapp.com

Comment: There are a lot of animation frameworks here. There should be one that will help you with what you need. https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#animation

Comment: @GIJOW Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I don't think this will help. I downloaded a sample project and it uses CAAnimation, but like I said, I need the delegates, which the Group will override

Comment: @AllenR Thanks for the link. I have visited the link before, but all I saw was wrappers for the existing animation functions. But there are a few custom ones, which might help me. I'll test some out and come back here when I have a result

Comment: I do not know of any other Apple built in animation frameworks with out doing something more complicated like graphics rendering. I know the animation frameworks are very powerful. I do find it hard to believe you have an animation that wouldn't be possible to implement with them.

Comment: @AllenR The animation framework is indeed very powerful. But the problem is coordinating these animations with multiple different delays, multiple different timing functions, sequential or simultaneously. These things are very difficult (if it even is possible) using the examples I gave. I now found a library which uses the CADisplayLink to get some sort of animation tick and does the calculations custom. Which is like the ValueAnimator on Android. It just passes the animated value on each tick.

Comment: I think I could implement the animation you described using `UIVew.animate`. If you post the android version you created I am sure I could replicated it. Or at least help you get there.

Comment: @AllenR I edited the question with the Android code. This code is from a button bar which has three buttons. The middle button is the camera button. The right button is only there during the first state. The left button stays the same except when going to or coming from first state. The middle button changes every time. They get translated out to the left and in from the right. But the states can also be reversed. So out to the right and in from the left. I'm curious how you would handle it in iOS

Comment: Can u share the .gif of your animation in android?

Comment: A gif is needed. It is pretty hard to get the feeling of an animation by code alone.

Comment: @AllenR I uploaded the animation to youtube and added the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've been working on my own solution using `CADisplayLink`. This is how the documentation describes `CADisplayLink`:

> CADisplayLink is a timer object that allows your application to
>   synchronize its drawing to the refresh rate of the display.

It basically provides a callback when to perform drawing code (so you can run your animation smoothly).

I am not going to explain everything during this answer, because it's going to be a lot of code and most of it should be clear. If something is unclear or you have a question you can comment below this answer.

This solution gives complete freedom on animations and provides the ability to coordinate them. I looked a lot to the `Animator` class on Android and wanted a similar syntax so we can easily port the animations from Android to iOS or the other way around. I've tested it for a few days now and removed some quirks as well. But enough talking, let's see some code!

This is the `Animator` class, which is the base structure for the animation classes:

```
class Animator {
    internal var displayLink: CADisplayLink? = nil
    internal var startTime: Double = 0.0
    var hasStarted: Bool = false
    var hasStartedAnimating: Bool = false
    var hasFinished: Bool = false
    var isManaged: Bool = false
    var isCancelled: Bool = false

    var onAnimationStart: () -> Void = {}
    var onAnimationEnd: () -> Void = {}
    var onAnimationUpdate: () -> Void = {}
    var onAnimationCancelled: () -> Void = {}

    public func start() {
        hasStarted = true

        startTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        if(!isManaged) {
            startDisplayLink()
        }
    }

    internal func startDisplayLink() {
        stopDisplayLink() // make sure to stop a previous running display link

        displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(animationTick))
        displayLink?.add(to: .main, forMode: .commonModes)
    }

    internal func stopDisplayLink() {
        displayLink?.invalidate()
        displayLink = nil
    }

    @objc internal func animationTick() {

    }

    public func cancel() {
        isCancelled = true
        onAnimationCancelled()
        if(!isManaged) {
            animationTick()
        }
    }
}
```

It contains all vitals like starting up the `CADisplayLink`, providing ability to stop `CADisplayLink` (when the animation is done), boolean values which indicates the state and some callbacks. You'll also notice the isManaged boolean. This boolean is when an `Animator` is controlled by a group. If it is, the group will provide the animation ticks and this class shouldn't start the `CADisplayLink`.

Next up is the `ValueAnimator`:

```
class ValueAnimator : Animator {
    public internal(set) var progress: Double = 0.0
    public internal(set) var interpolatedProgress: Double = 0.0

    var duration: Double = 0.3
    var delay: Double = 0
    var interpolator: Interpolator = EasingInterpolator(ease: .LINEAR)

    override func animationTick() {
        // In case this gets called after we finished
        if(hasFinished) {
            return
        }

        let elapsed: Double = (isCancelled) ? self.duration : CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime - delay

        if(elapsed < 0) {
            return
        }

        if(!hasStartedAnimating) {
            hasStartedAnimating = true
            onAnimationStart()
        }

        if(duration <= 0) {
            progress = 1.0
        } else {
            progress = min(elapsed / duration, 1.0)
        }
        interpolatedProgress = interpolator.interpolate(elapsedTimeRate: progress)

        updateAnimationValues()
        onAnimationUpdate()

        if(elapsed >= duration) {
            endAnimation()
        }
    }

    private func endAnimation() {
        hasFinished = true
        if(!isManaged) {
            stopDisplayLink()
        }
        onAnimationEnd()
    }

    internal func updateAnimationValues() {

    }
}
```

This class is the base class for all value animators. But it could also be used to do the animation on your own if you wish to do the calculations yourself. You'll probably noticed the `Interpolator` and `interpolatedProgress` here. The `Interpolator` class will be shown in a bit. This class provides the easing of the animation. This is where `interpolatedProgress` comes in. `progress` is just the linear progress from 0.0 to 1.0, but `interpolatedProgress` could have a different value for the easing. For example when `progress` has the value 0.2, `interpolatedProgress` might already have 0.4 based on what easing you'll use. Also make sure to use `interpolatedProgress` to calculate the right value. An example and the first subclass of `ValueAnimator` is below.

Below is the `CGFloatValueAnimator` which, as the name would suggest, animates CGFloat values:

```
class CGFloatValueAnimator : ValueAnimator {
    private let startValue: CGFloat
    private let endValue: CGFloat
    public private(set) var animatedValue: CGFloat

    init(startValue: CGFloat, endValue: CGFloat) {
        self.startValue = startValue
        self.endValue = endValue
        self.animatedValue = startValue
    }

    override func updateAnimationValues() {
        animatedValue = startValue + CGFloat(Double(endValue - startValue) * interpolatedProgress)
    }
}
```

This is an example of how to subclass `ValueAnimator` and you can make many more like this if you need others like doubles or integers for example. You just provide a start and end value and the `Animator` calculates based on the `interpolatedProgress` what the current `animatedValue` is. You can use this `animatedValue` to update your view. I'll show an example at the end.

Because I mentioned `Interpolator` a couple times already, we'll continue to the `Interpolator` now:

```
protocol Interpolator {
    func interpolate(elapsedTimeRate: Double) -> Double
}
```

It's just a protocol which you can implement yourself. I'll show you a part of the `EasingInterpolator` class I use myself. I can provide more if someone needs it.

```
class EasingInterpolator : Interpolator {
    private let ease: Ease

    init(ease: Ease) {
        self.ease = ease
    }

    func interpolate(elapsedTimeRate: Double) -> Double {
        switch (ease) {
            case Ease.LINEAR:
                return elapsedTimeRate
            case Ease.SINE_IN:
                return (1.0 - cos(elapsedTimeRate * Double.pi / 2.0))
            case Ease.SINE_OUT:
                return sin(elapsedTimeRate * Double.pi / 2.0)
            case Ease.SINE_IN_OUT:
                return (-0.5 * (cos(Double.pi * elapsedTimeRate) - 1.0))
            case Ease.CIRC_IN:
                return  -(sqrt(1.0 - elapsedTimeRate * elapsedTimeRate) - 1.0)
            case Ease.CIRC_OUT:
                let newElapsedTimeRate = elapsedTimeRate - 1
                return sqrt(1.0 - newElapsedTimeRate * newElapsedTimeRate)
            case Ease.CIRC_IN_OUT:
                var newElapsedTimeRate = elapsedTimeRate * 2.0
                if (newElapsedTimeRate < 1.0) {
                    return (-0.5 * (sqrt(1.0 - newElapsedTimeRate * newElapsedTimeRate) - 1.0))
                }
                newElapsedTimeRate -= 2.0
                return (0.5 * (sqrt(1 - newElapsedTimeRate * newElapsedTimeRate) + 1.0))

            default:
                return elapsedTimeRate

        }
    }
}
```

These are just a few examples of the calculations for specific easings. I actually ported all easings made for Android located here: https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/EasingInterpolator.

Before I show an example I have one more class to show. Which is the class that allows grouping of animators:

```
class AnimatorSet : Animator {
    private var animators: [Animator] = []

    var delay: Double = 0
    var playSequential: Bool = false

    override func start() {
        super.start()
    }

    override func animationTick() {
        // In case this gets called after we finished
        if(hasFinished) {
            return
        }

        let elapsed = CACurrentMediaTime() - startTime - delay
        if(elapsed < 0 && !isCancelled) {
            return
        }

        if(!hasStartedAnimating) {
            hasStartedAnimating = true
            onAnimationStart()
        }

        var finishedNumber = 0
        for animator in animators {
            if(!animator.hasStarted) {
                animator.start()
            }
            animator.animationTick()
            if(animator.hasFinished) {
                finishedNumber += 1
            } else {
                if(playSequential) {
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if(finishedNumber >= animators.count) {
            endAnimation()
        }
    }

    private func endAnimation() {
        hasFinished = true
        if(!isManaged) {
            stopDisplayLink()
        }
        onAnimationEnd()
    }

    public func addAnimator(_ animator: Animator) {
        animator.isManaged = true
        animators.append(animator)
    }

    public func addAnimators(_ animators: [Animator]) {
        for animator in animators {
            animator.isManaged = true
            self.animators.append(animator)
        }
    }

    override func cancel() {
        for animator in animators {
            animator.cancel()
        }

        super.cancel()
    }
}
```

As you can see, here is where I set the `isManaged` boolean. You can put multiple animators you make inside this class to coordinate them. And because this class also extends `Animator` you can also put in another `AnimatorSet` or multiple. By default it runs all the animations simultaneously, but if the `playSequential` is set to true, it will run all animations in order.

Time for a demo:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let animView = UIView()
        animView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        self.view.addSubview(animView)

        animView.snp.makeConstraints { maker in
            maker.width.height.equalTo(100)
            maker.center.equalTo(self.view)
        }

        let translateAnimator = CGFloatValueAnimator(startValue: 0, endValue: 100)
        translateAnimator.delay = 1.0
        translateAnimator.duration = 1.0
        translateAnimator.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(ease: .CIRC_IN_OUT)
        translateAnimator.onAnimationStart = {
            animView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }
        translateAnimator.onAnimationEnd = {
            animView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
        translateAnimator.onAnimationUpdate = {
            animView.transform.tx = translateAnimator.animatedValue
        }

        let alphaAnimator = CGFloatValueAnimator(startValue: animView.alpha, endValue: 0)
        alphaAnimator.delay = 1.0
        alphaAnimator.duration = 1.0
        alphaAnimator.interpolator = EasingInterpolator(ease: .CIRC_IN_OUT)
        alphaAnimator.onAnimationUpdate = {
            animView.alpha = alphaAnimator.animatedValue
        }

        let animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
//        animatorSet.playSequential = true // Uncomment this to play animations in order
        animatorSet.addAnimator(translateAnimator)
        animatorSet.addAnimator(alphaAnimator)

        animatorSet.start()
    }

}
```

I think most of this will speak for itself. I created a view which translates the x and fades out. For each animation you implement the `onAnimationUpdate` callback to alter values used in the view, like in this case the translation x and alpha.

**Note:** In contradiction to Android, the duration and delay are in seconds here instead of milliseconds.

We are working with this code right now and it works great! I already wrote some animation stuff in our Android app. I could easily port the animation to iOS with some minimal rewriting and the animation works exactly the same! I could copy the code written in my question, changed the Kotlin code to Swift, applied the `onAnimationUpdate`, changed the duration and delays to seconds and the animation worked like a charm.

I want to release this as an open source library, but I have not yet done this. I'll update this answer when I released it.

If you have any question about the code or how it works, feel free to ask.

Comment: Did you ever get to package this up, because this is awesome!

Comment: @hank Thanks! :) We still use it all the time. At the moment we have an internal library for our company, but I'm working on making some libraries open source! But for the moment you'll have to do with these code snippets. If I don't forget I'll update this page with the package link when we open source it!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start on the animation I think you are looking for. If you do not like the timing of the slides then you could switch out the `UIView.animate` with `.curveEaseInOut` for `CAKeyframeAnimation` where you could control each frame more granularly. You would want a `CAKeyFrameAnimation` for each view you are animating.

[image]

This is a playground and you can copy and paste it into an empty playground to see it in action.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let bottomBar = UIView()
    let orangeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: 75, height: 75))
    let yellow = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 35, height: 35))
    let magenta = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: 30, width: 15, height: 15))
    let cyan = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 20, width: 35, height: 35))
    let brown = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 30, width:
    15, height: 15))
    let leftBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 10, width: 125, height: 75))

    func setup() {

        let reset = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        reset.backgroundColor = .white
        reset.addTarget(self, action: #selector(resetAnimation), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(reset)

        bottomBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 100, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 100)
        bottomBar.backgroundColor = .purple
        self.view.addSubview(bottomBar)

        orangeButton.backgroundColor = .orange
        orangeButton.center.x = bottomBar.frame.size.width / 2
        orangeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(orangeTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        orangeButton.clipsToBounds = true
        bottomBar.addSubview(orangeButton)

        yellow.backgroundColor = .yellow
        orangeButton.addSubview(yellow)

        magenta.backgroundColor = .magenta
        magenta.alpha = 0
        orangeButton.addSubview(magenta)

        // Left box is an invisible bounding box to get the effect that the view appeared from nowhere
        // Clips to bounds so you cannot see the view when it has not been animated
        // Try setting to false
        leftBox.clipsToBounds = true
        bottomBar.addSubview(leftBox)

        cyan.backgroundColor = .cyan
        leftBox.addSubview(cyan)

        brown.backgroundColor = .brown
        brown.alpha = 0
        leftBox.addSubview(brown)
    }

    @objc func orangeTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        // Perform animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

            self.yellow.frame = CGRect(x: -20, y: 30, width: 15, height: 15)
            self.yellow.alpha = 0

            self.magenta.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 35, height: 35)
            self.magenta.alpha = 1

            self.cyan.frame = CGRect(x: -150, y: 30, width: 15, height: 15)
            self.cyan.alpha = 0

            self.brown.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 20, width: 35, height: 35)
            self.brown.alpha = 1

        }, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func resetAnimation() {
        // Reset the animation back to the start
        yellow.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 35, height: 35)
        yellow.alpha = 1
        magenta.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 30, width: 15, height: 15)
        magenta.alpha = 0
        cyan.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 20, width: 35, height: 35)
        cyan.alpha = 1
        brown.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 30, width: 15, height: 15)
        brown.alpha = 0
    }

}
let viewController = ViewController()
viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 667)
viewController.view.backgroundColor = .blue
viewController.setup()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

Comment: I think you came pretty close, but I'm missing a few things. Like the custom timing functions (I think I used cubic, quint and circ in Android) per animation. I would prefer to use the existing view and change it half way (so I don't have to create 6 different buttons instead of 3). The scale change when animating in happens with a small delay so you can see it better. But pretty cool that you came this close though. I am currently working on a custom solution which behaves kindoff like the Animators from Android, where I have full freedom. I'll post it when I'm done

Comment: You should be able to do the same animation with `CAKeyFrameAnimtions` and `UIPropertyAnimator` has `cubic`, `quint` and `circ` timing functions. The same result should be able to be achieved with those. The code becomes pretty verbose which I think is a downside. Here is a post describing how to use `UIPropertyAnimator` with custom curves https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161465/how-to-create-custom-easing-function-with-core-animation

Comment: Okay, that solves one problem. But to coordinate the whole thing together would be a pain in the ass using those options. Because I'm grouping animation (which I think is possible with CAKeyFrameAnimation, but destroys all child delegates) which inside an animation could have different delays. Anyway, what I'm working on has all the stuff I want without the cumbersome stuff

Comment: In case you wanted to see what my solution is, I posted my answer here as well.